# OLE DB Provider issue in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I am getting this below when try to load .MDB dile using OPENROWSET().How to resolve this issue?

> Msg 7399 The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked
>   server "(null)" reported an error. Provider caused a server fault in
>   an external process.
>
> Msg 7303 Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider
>   "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".

Comment: Is that provider installed on the Server? in `SSMS`, drill down into `Server Objects > Linked Servers > Providers`. Look for `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` Also, please post your query.

Comment: Yes, Provider has installed.

Comment: When I execute manually it succeded but it failed in SQL server job.

Comment: What is the SQL Services (SQL Server and SQL Agent) running under? Meaning account? Also, that should have been stated in the original post, that you can run it in SSMS, but not as a SQL agent job.